# Switch window in PySimpleGUI with keyboard input (left/right arrow)

Tags: python, input, pysimplegui

I have 3 windows in terms of sg.Frame and would like to switch the windows via keyboard input. However the window does not respones while the buttons work well.

```
layout = [
            [
                sg.Column(layout1, key='-COL1-'), # layoutX is a page interms of sg.Frame
                sg.Column(layout2, visible=False, key='-COL2-'),
                sg.Column(layout3, visible=False, key='-COL3-')
            ],
            [
            #     sg.Button('Cycle Layout'),
                sg.Button('-PREV-'),
                sg.Button('1'),
                sg.Button('2'),
                sg.Button('3'),
                sg.Button('-NEXT-'),
            #     sg.Button('Exit')
            ]
        ]

window = sg.Window('Swapping the contents of a window', layout) #, size = (1024, 800)

layout = 1  # The currently visible layout

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    print(event, values)
    if event in (None, 'Exit'):
        break

    window.bind('<Right>', '-NEXT-')
    window.bind('<Left>', '-PREV-')
    window.bind('<Down>', 'Exit')

    if event == '-NEXT-' and layout < 3:
        window[f'-COL{layout}-'].update(visible=False)
        layout = layout + 1
        window[f'-COL{layout}-'].update(visible=True)

    elif event == '-PREV-' and layout > 1:
        window[f'-COL{layout}-'].update(visible=False)
        layout -= 1
        window[f'-COL{layout}-'].update(visible=True)

    elif event in '123':
        window[f'-COL{layout}-'].update(visible=False)
        layout = int(event)
        window[f'-COL{layout}-'].update(visible=True)

window.close()
```

How can I modify? Thanks very much!

Comment: What are `layout1`, `layout2`, `layout3`?

Answer (score 0):

The statements for binding the keyboards should be placed after window finalized and before your event loop, then it will work before your event loop start.

```py
window = sg.Window('Swapping the contents of a window', layout, finalize=True) #, size = (1024, 800)

window.bind('<Right>', '-NEXT-')
window.bind('<Left>', '-PREV-')
window.bind('<Down>', 'Exit')
```